# What is the likihood of get hacked or infected using an end-of-life Windows 7?

Tags: windows, virus

How likely is one to get hacked or infected using an end-of-life Windows 7 if you dont upgrade to either Windows 8 or Windows 10  ?

Comment: Hi Shannan, welcome! This question is too unfocused. The likelihood will vary significantly if you are a nation state target or an average Joe, or if you have significant tech expertise or not, and so on... What exactly are you trying to defend against?

Comment: There are a lot of questions about using end-of-life OSes. See question IDs 173572, 51297, 173572, 57203, 101104, etc. (`security.stackexchange.com/q/<ID>`). Since your question is covered by a hundred other existing questions, it would be a duplicate, overly broad, and in this case, I think also primarily opinion-based. If you have a specific and objective question, like "how do I protect against X?" or "is X possible now that it is EOL?" then please edit your message. Otherwise, "how likely is getting hacked" is way too broad/opinionated/covered elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your knowledge about IT security is reflected in the question in that you cannot focus on your specific threats and risks since you don't know them, then the likelihood of getting hacked is high enough to be worried. Note that this is not meant to denounce your knowledge, most people don't know much about IT security.

But if one is not sufficiently aware of the specific threats and risks one cannot behave in a way which mitigates the risks. With proper risk management instead even if a system which is long out of support can be used in a sufficiently secure way. This is actually done a lot in industrial environments where long out of support systems like Windows XP or Windows 2000 are still in use. But these systems tend to be used only for a specific task and only tend to run in a trusted environment with no or only very restricted communication to other networks.